# How can I access the $_ variable from the calling frame?

Tags: raku

In Raku, I want to replace `$_<something>` with `Ƥ<something>` where `$_` does `Associative`.

Suppose I have something like

```
my %h = %( aaa => { say $_<content> } );
%h<aaa>.( %( :content('Hello world'), ) );
```

This produces `Hello world`.

Since the `$_` will be appearing lots of times, I would like to replace it with `Ƥ` (not just to save one character, but for existence checking, etc).

So what I want is:

```
my %h = %( aaa => { say Ƥ<content> } );
%h<aaa>.( %( :content('Hello world  '), ) );
```

I can write a prefix operator `sub prefix:<Ƥ>(Str $key)` However, I need to access the topic variable of the calling context, that is the value of `$_` inside the block pointed to by 'aaa'.

Here's the code I tried:

```
sub prefix:<Ƥ>(Str $key) {
    my $topic = callframe(1).my<$_>;
      # debug point
    if $topic ~~ Associative and $topic{ $key }:exists {
      # All good so return a string
      return $topic{ $key }.Str
    }
      # Treat undefined as empty string
    return ''
}
```

Problem I have is that at debug point, `$topic` is `Rakudo::Internals::LoweredAwayLexical`.

Is what I am trying possible?

Answer (score 5):

In short: use `CALLERS::`

```
$_ = 42;
{ say CALLERS::<$_> }()  # 42
```

For more info, see https://docs.raku.org/language/packages#Pseudo-packages

Comment: If I insert `CALLERS::<$_>` in place of `callframe(1).my<$_>`, I get exactly the same result

Comment: Hmmmm  I guess I missed the `LoweredAwayLexical`, which is basically the optimizer deciding there's nobody using the `$_` in that scope, so it can be optimized away.  Maybe it would be better to just wrap the check in a `try`, like: `if try CALLERS::<$_>{ $key }:exists {`